# What exactly is the "présentation analytique" while applying for MCF (assistant professor) positions in France on Galaxie portal?

Tags: job-search, cv, europe, france

I've passed the qualification in mathematics and I'm trying to apply for some assistant professor ([Maître des Conférences](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre_de_conf%C3%A9rences_(France)) - MCF) positions in France, using the Galaxie portal. However, I see that there's no option to submit a CV, which I submitted during the qualification process, but there's an option to submit "*présentation analytique*"?

This makes me wonder: **what exactly is a presentation analytique** (analytical presentation)? Also how do I submit my CV for this position?

So I contacted some administrative officials processing the MCF applications, and here's the response I got: (translated to English)

"*The analytical presentation is a description of your academic and/or research background. Whether in the past or in the future you must present your experience by detailing your research and your publications.
Most often, the analytical presentation begins first as a CV and then, following this CV, you present your career path analytically as described above.
The definition of *analytical presentation* is as follows:
a CV giving an analytical presentation of the work, books, articles, achievements and activities, mentioning those that the candidate intends to present at the audition*"

**So to double check: if I combine two documents: (1) my academic CV that details my education, work experience, teaching experience, publication details (number of articles, journals where published etc.) and references etc. and (2) a statement of research interests where I detail my work, the results/theorems, and future plan for work, will this constitute a proper *presentation analytique*? Or, do I need to include (3) a description of research project that I'm pursuing at present and intend to continue for the next two years?**

Any help from people familiar with the French academic system would be greatly appreciated!

Thank you in advance and kind regards.

Comment: Quick and dirty. Check this person
http://www.iheal.univ-paris3.fr/fr/annuaire-profil/dumont-juliette
she is maitre de conference, and she has a "CV analytique"
http://www.iheal.univ-paris3.fr/sites/www.iheal.univ-paris3.fr/files/CV%20J.%20Dumont%20nov.%202020.pdf
good luck!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> what exactly is a presentation analytique (analytical presentation)?

This depends on the field. In e.g. math, it's common for the "analytical CV" to include an actual CV, a presentation of your research up to now (most important publications/results, comparison to the state of the art etc), and your research projects for the next few years, as well as a teaching statement. I can imagine that things may be different in other disciplines. It sounds like you're already on the right track.

> Also how do I submit my CV for this position?

Upload the PDF in the box that says "CV" on Galaxie. You can only upload one file so you should combine the actual CV and the "analytical" part. For some (most) applications, you will also have to upload it on a website provided by the university along with other locally relevant information/documents.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm indeed in math/applied math, so this sums it up nicely. I'm wondering whether it's a good idea to add some relevant definitions and previous research to make the exposition complete? It seems yes, but after doing so, and even after deliberately keeping one particular section short, my research experience part alone took me 13 pages to write, with 4 diagrams in it, one page bibliography.  I'm wondering whether it's ridiculously long? To ease reading though, I separated my results out and instructed the readers how to find them quickly in the document.

Comment: @ScienceMan It's fine. My own "analytic CV" was 19 pages long and I got the job in the end.

Comment: Thank you @N.I. for your comment! I was still wondering what parts of the research experience will the jury look at? Will they really go through all the details the candidate has to say (introduction to the problem, state of the art, her/his contribution and potential open problems...), or will they just jump to the main results and theorems proved by the candidate and see whether they make sense and connect with the theme the MCF is sought for? One could imagine that reading all the 12-15 pages from every candidate describing their research is very time consuming; so I'm curious!