# Do I need to write a cover letter or something specific in my présentation analytique to the math department for MCF position application?

Tags: mathematics, job-search, job, assistant-professor, france

This question is a continuation of [my earlier question](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/182952/what-exactly-is-the-pr%C3%A9sentation-analytique-while-applying-for-mcf-assistant) related to the job applications for French [Maître de Conférences position](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ma%C3%AEtre_de_conf%C3%A9rences_(France)) for mathematics ([CNU section](https://conseil-national-des-universites.fr/cnu/#/) 25) and applied mathematics ([CNU section](https://conseil-national-des-universites.fr/cnu/#/) 26).

**My question is:** While I understand that the *"présentation analytique"* (in English: analytical presentation) will have three main parts: i) CV, ii) research experience and future research projects, and iii) teaching experience and teaching philosophy, what's not clear to me is: **do I need to tailor my "présentation analytique" according to each department I apply to?** So in essence, should the "présentation analytique" vary from department to department? Or perhaps will there be a *fourth section* where I'm supposed to write a ***cover letter** directed to the department* explaining why I'd like to work in that department?

Thank you in advance!